# Swift - create different instances of custom Views

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am working on an app in which the user has access to different lists. I will show some pictures for a better understanding.

This is my "Main-Menue" where the user can add custom `cells` ("Main Wishlist", "List1", List2",..) to a `UICollectionView`.

[image]

Each `cell` should in the end "contain" its own `View` with a `TableView` inside of it. The `View` appears by clicking on the `cell`:

[image]

This is how I let the `View` appear:

```
    @IBAction func createListButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    // "Liste erstellen" button was tapped
    self.appDidEnterBackgroundHandler()

    if let txt = listNameTextfield.text {

        self.newListTextfield.resignFirstResponder()

        // append user-entered text to the data array
        self.theData.append(txt)
        self.imageData.append(self.image!)

        self.view.addSubview(self.theCustomWishlistView)
        // constrain CustomWishlistView
        self.theCustomWishlistView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 120.0).isActive = true
        self.theCustomWishlistView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        self.theCustomWishlistView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 30.0).isActive = true
        self.theCustomWishlistView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -30.0).isActive = true
        self.theCustomWishlistView.wishlistImage.image = self.image
        self.theCustomWishlistView.wishlistLabel.text = txt
        self.theCustomWishlistView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 1000)
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(containerView)


        // reload the collection view
        theCollectionView.reloadData()
        theCollectionView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: {
            (result) in
            // scroll to make newly added row visible (if needed)
            let i = self.theCollectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) - 1
            let idx = IndexPath(item: i, section: 0)
            self.theCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: idx, at: .bottom, animated: true)

            // close (hide) the "New List" view
            self.closeButtonTappedNewList(nil)
        })
    }
}
```

**Problem:**  Like I previously said, there should be an individual `View` be created for each cell but at the moment every `cell` contains the same `customWishlistView`.

This is how I create my `customWishlistView`:

```
lazy var theCustomWishlistView: CustomWishlistView = {
    let v = CustomWishlistView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    return v
}()
```

Comment: Where are you creating the `theCustomWishlistView` variable? Currently, I think it's on your `UIViewController`, so you're basically adding the same view to each of your cells.

Comment: yes, in my `UIViewController` . So what can I do to change that?

Comment: Move the creation of `theCustomWishlistView` to right before you're adding it to your view. It should suffice.

Comment: do you mean inside the function? That is not working because I need to access it outside of it aswell

Comment: @Chris Make a method that returns CustomWishlistView. Current code produces shared instance.

Comment: @AlexanderVolkov sorry I am just a beginner. How would I do that?:)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
lazy var theCustomWishlistView: CustomWishlistView = {
    let v = CustomWishlistView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    return v
}()
```

to

```
func createCustomWishlistView() -> CustomWishlistView {
    let v = CustomWishlistView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    return v
}
```

and use it

instead of `self.theCustomWishlistView`

create it for every cell:

```
let theCustomWishlistView = createCustomWishlistView()
...
```

Comment: that look like it could work, but I am having a problem because I need to access `theCustomWishlistView` in another function because I need to perfrom `CGAffineTransform` on it.

Comment: @Chris that's another problem. You should organize code properly. View controller should not do such things like you mentioned - view transformation. May be you can put that into CustomWishlistView itself.

Comment: oh ok :/ I just asked a question about this. Maybe you can have a look at it :)