# Swift - access instance of UIView from another function

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

In my project the user can create a `UIView` ("CustomWishlistView") like this:

```
func createCustomWishlistView() -> CustomWishlistView {
    let v = CustomWishlistView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    return v
}

@IBAction func createListButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {


    // "Liste erstellen" button was tapped
    self.appDidEnterBackgroundHandler()

    if let txt = listNameTextfield.text {

        self.newListTextfield.resignFirstResponder()

        // append user-entered text to the data array
        self.theData.append(txt)
        self.imageData.append(self.image!)

        let theCustomWishlistView = createCustomWishlistView()

        self.view.addSubview(theCustomWishlistView)
        // constrain CustomWishlistView
        theCustomWishlistView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 120.0).isActive = true
        theCustomWishlistView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        theCustomWishlistView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 30.0).isActive = true
        theCustomWishlistView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -30.0).isActive = true
        theCustomWishlistView.wishlistImage.image = self.image
        theCustomWishlistView.wishlistLabel.text = txt
        theCustomWishlistView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 1000)

        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(containerView)


        // reload the collection view
        theCollectionView.reloadData()
        theCollectionView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: {
            (result) in
            // scroll to make newly added row visible (if needed)
            let i = self.theCollectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) - 1
            let idx = IndexPath(item: i, section: 0)
            self.theCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: idx, at: .bottom, animated: true)

            // close (hide) the "New List" view
            self.closeButtonTappedNewList(nil)
        })
    }
}
```

I `transform` that `view` so it is not visible at first. It should appear after the user clicks on a `cell` inside a `UICollectionView`. My code for this (inside `cellForItemAt`) looks like this:

```
    if indexPath.item <= theData.count {
           let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ContentCell", for: indexPath) as! ContentCell

            cell.testLabel.text = theData[indexPath.item - 1]

            cell.buttonView.setImage(imageData[indexPath.item - 1], for: .normal)

        cell.customWishlistTapCallback = {
            // let CustomWishlistView appear
//            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
//                theCustomWishlistView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
//            })
            // let welcomeText disappear
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.welcomeTextLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
            })
        }
           return cell
       }
```

My problem is that I can not let my `customWishlistView` appear because I can not access it. Is there a way to fix this problem? :)

Comment: You need to make `theCustomWishlistView` an instance variable

Comment: how do I do that? Sorry I am just a beginner

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `theCustomWishlistView` an instance variable like below. You don't show the entire class code, so my solution is as complete as I can make it without seeing the rest of your code

```swift
class CustomViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var theCustomWishlistView: UIView?

    func createCustomWishlistView() -> CustomWishlistView {
        let v = CustomWishlistView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        v.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        return v
    }

    @IBAction func createListButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        // "Liste erstellen" button was tapped
        self.appDidEnterBackgroundHandler()

        if let txt = listNameTextfield.text {

            self.newListTextfield.resignFirstResponder()

            // append user-entered text to the data array
            self.theData.append(txt)
            self.imageData.append(self.image!)

            let wishlistView = createCustomWishlistView()

            self.view.addSubview(wishlistView)
            // constrain wishlistView
            wishlistView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 120.0).isActive = true
            wishlistView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            wishlistView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 30.0).isActive = true
            wishlistView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -30.0).isActive = true
            wishlistView.wishlistImage.image = self.image
            wishlistView.wishlistLabel.text = txt
            wishlistView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 1000)

            // retain wishlist view in instance variable
            self.theCustomWishlistView = wishlistView
            self.view.bringSubviewToFront(containerView)

            // reload the collection view
            theCollectionView.reloadData()
            theCollectionView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: {
                (result) in
                // scroll to make newly added row visible (if needed)
                guard let i = self.theCollectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) else { return }
                let idx = IndexPath(item: i - 1, section: 0)
                self.theCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: idx, at: .bottom, animated: true)
                // close (hide) the "New List" view
                self.closeButtonTappedNewList(nil)
            })

        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return theData.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

       let _cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ContentCell", for: indexPath)

        guard let cell = _cell as? ContentCell else { return _cell }

        cell.testLabel.text = theData[indexPath.item - 1]

        cell.buttonView.setImage(imageData[indexPath.item - 1], for: .normal)

        cell.customWishlistTapCallback = {
            // let CustomWishlistView appear
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
                self.theCustomWishlistView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
            })
            // let welcomeText disappear
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.welcomeTextLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
            })
        }
       return cell
   }

}
```

Comment: Your answer before the edit actually made more sense to me. Your answer now doesn't really work with my code. Here is my full project: https://github.com/chriskonnerth/Wishlist

Comment: That probably has to do with the misuse of the strict optional wrapper (`!`)  and not copying my code verbatim regarding the optional wrappers., however, I returned my answer to adhere your use of the optional wrapper

Comment: Can you update your question itself to include all of the code for your view controller?

Comment: my code for my `ViewController` is super messy :( I can not really simplify it more than I already did. Bad question I know but I don't know what else to do :/

Comment: I tried implementing your answer but it does not really work the way it should because it doesn't create a new `View` every time  for each `cell` but instead it always overwrites the old one. I hope you can understand what I mean

Comment: You might want to have a look at my last question to understand my problem a bit better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59161628/swift-create-different-instances-of-custom-views/59164172?noredirect=1#comment104555434_59164172

Comment: I see. I assumed you were trying to overwrite. If you want to keep adding views you can change theCustomWishlistView to an array and instead append instances. This is a new requirement that this question does not address. You should make having multiple views a separate question. This one was simply trying to access the view as an instance variable